# Error when trying to access member profile page

Tags: error, members

When trying to access a member profile page using the trigger url (e.g. mysite.com/profile) I get the following error:

```
The member profile you requested is currently not available
```

I've checked all the things I can think of. I have seen it once before on a site but given that the normal EE sites I build have very limited membership features (i.e. just the site admins) and I normally turn off member profiles/obfuscate the url I'm at a loss to work out why this is happening.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and found a fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the trigger itself is not enough - you need to append your action to the last segment

At least, thats what I figured to be the problem when I had this. I had to go to /profiles/login/ and /profiles/profile/ etc and then this worked fine.

Although this could be a bug - but is the way that I've done it.

Comment: That looks like it might be it! I can't accept this answer for another 8 minutes though!

Answer (score 3):

You do need that last segment to trigger a specific profile and template.

Comment: So my original question stands. Adding the extra segment makes it work.

Comment: I wonder if it's not working without that additional segment because I am removing index.php via htaccess.

Comment: I don't think removing index.php via .htaccess should have a negative effect in this context. I do it all the time.